# Symfony routing not working

Tags: php, symfony

I am using a normal host (i.e **access to web pages via public_html and no access to php (apache) configuration**).

so here what i did

1. renamed my web dir => public_html
2. renamed app.php (prod application) to index.php

I've also added a route to my page (template) named "littlebird"

**Problem**

when I call *www.mywebsite.com/littlebird* => 404 page not found

but when I use *www.mywebsite.com/index.php/littlebird* every thing works just fine.

Comment: You have `mod_rewrite` turned off

Comment: @zerkms can u please explain ???

Comment: check if `mod_rewrite` is turned on then check rewrite rules in `.htaccess`

Comment: I only have **Options -Indexes** in my .htaccess @zerkms

Comment: then you have lost your `.htaccess` somewhere. Symfony2 is shipped with a `.htaccess` with more than 50 lines in total: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess

Comment: @zerkms if you would, please add it as new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original guess was that you didn't have the `mod_rewrite` turned on.

But during our discussion we've found that you have replaced the original `.htaccess` with something else.

The original `.htaccess` could be found by this address: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you don't have a `index.php` value within `DirectoryIndex`.

Try editing your `.htaccess` file that is located in `littlebird` and adding/updating it with:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `DirectoryIndex`

Comment: @Badik Ali: symfony2 requires *deep* knowledge of how the whole technologies stack works. So I hardly doubt that *guessing* is a symfony-way.

Comment: @BadikAli: OK, you will be able to distinguish Symfony's 404 and Apache 404. So, which one do you get? Have you make sure that `.htaccess` rewrites you URL to `index.php` and not `app.php`?

Comment: @jperovic I think Apache 404

Comment: OK, then follow `@zerkms`'s suggestion about checking if you have `mod_rewrite` turned on. Usually, `.htaccess` has condition checks if it's enabled. The most basic, and quickest/dirtiest, way is to just comment out those `<If>` tags. If page crashes then with HTTP500, you most probably don't have `mod_rewrite`...

Comment: I only have **Options -Indexes** in my .htaccess @jperovic

Comment: Are you referring to `littlebird/.htaccess` file? That file should contain a lot of lines (like 20-ish or 30-ish)